# How to print a word document duplex using OLE autimation with delphi xe3

Tags: delphi, printing, ms-word, delphi-xe3

I am currently trying to print a created document on both sides of paper using the code below. But i cannot find any way to change it so the printer prints duplex without the user having to select print duplex.

If you have any suggestions it would be great.

Code:

```
Dlg := wrdApp.Dialogs.Item(88);
dlg.show;
           wrdApp.PrintOut(Background := false,
                             range := dlg.Range,
                             From := dlg.From,
                             To := dlg.To,
                             PageType := dlg.Type,
                             Copies := dlg.NumCopies,
                             Pages := dlg.Pages,
                             Collate := dlg.Collate,
                             PrintToFile := dlg.PrintToFile,
                             ManualDuplexPrint := dlg.DuplexPrint,
                             PrintZoomColumn := dlg.PrintZoomColumn,
                             PrintZoomRow := dlg.PrintZoomRow,
                             PrintZoomPaperWidth := dlg.PrintZoomPaperWidth,
                             PrintZoomPaperHeight := dlg.PrintZoomPaperHeight);
```

I want to execute the print without having to call the `dlg.show;` command.

Comment: i just noticed, that my document prints twice, the dlg.show; also prints the file, so what im hoping is to cancel that 1 out. and just use the wrdApp.PrintOut() command once i know th duplex settings to print it on short edge, also i need to know how to change the papersize to A4, and set the orentation to landskape, and the printer to print to.

Comment: These are all print dialog settings. But for many printers you have to go into the printer properties dialogs as well - duplex printing is one example. Doesn't this mean that you would have to to that too, from code?

Comment: i don't believe its necessary, if the settings can be changed with the dlg.show dialog, i believe it should be able to change from within Delphi code, by just appropriating the ManualDuplexPrint with the right settings.